# Converting a ( text file ) into any format of image ( png ) C++

Tags: c++, png, robots.txt

can some one please provide me with a C++ code, for transforming a text file to any format of images, I know the image will have no meaning, but I am doing this thing for security reasons

can some one please provide me with a C++ code, if there is no C++ , then JAVA will work

I really checked alot on the net, and found really nothing

I know every one will say do ur job alone, but I am really out of time 
please this is serious 
I am even willing to pay if some one is goin to do it

thanx in advance

Comment: This community provides help for technical questions.  We like to help but aren't *here* for hire.  Another site might provide a better infrastructure for contract programming if that's what you really need.

Comment: Well I mentioned the payin thing, if some one knows it, I have no problem paying him ..... I know that this place is for help and not for hiring .... Thanx for ur comment .....

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, what you want the transformation to be, but you can just treat the text from the text file as an array of unsigned chars and store this data as an RGB array into a BMP or another lossless compressed image format. For loading and saving images there are a plenty of libraries (OpenIL/DevIL is quite simple and useful).

This way the image has no meaning but is still a valid image, in contrast to just changing the file extension.

**EDIT:** Your luck I'm currently bored. The following could work using OpenIL:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <IL/il.h>

void encode(const char *infile, const char *outfile)
{
    std::ifstream in(infile);
    in.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    unsigned int size = in.tellg();
    unsigned int width = (size+6) / 3;
    width = int(sqrt(double(width))) + 1;
    char *data = new char[width*width*3];
    *(unsigned int*)data = size;
    in.seekg(0);
    in.read(data+sizeof(unsigned int), size);
    unsigned int image;
    ilGenImages(1, &image);
    ilBindImage(image);
    ilTexImage(width, width, 1, 3, IL_RGB, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    ilSaveImage(outfile);
    ilDeleteImages(1, &image);
    delete[] data;
}

void decode(const char *infile, const char *outfile)
{
    unsigned int image;
    ilGenImages(1, &image);
    ilBindImage(image);
    ilLoadImage(infile);
    ilConvertImage(IL_RGB, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
    unsigned char *data = ilGetData();
    unsigned int size = *(unsigned int*)data;
    std::ofstream out(outfile);
    out.write((char*)data+sizeof(unsigned int), size);
    ilDeleteImages(1, &image);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ilInit();
    ilOriginFunc(IL_ORIGIN_LOWER_LEFT);
    ilEnable(IL_ORIGIN_SET);
    ilEnable(IL_FILE_OVERWRITE);
    encode(argv[1], argv[2]);
    decode(argv[2], argv[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Added complete sourcecode of test program. Tested it on my Windows system with this code as input and the PNG format and it works.

Comment: I have been told alot some one told me to use openCV, others told me to use pnglib , others said something to do with bitmap

Comment: It is really just some 10-30 lines of code with a library as simple as OpenIL.

Comment: the transformation is easy for example u wrote an article which u want others not to be able to read it when u send it through email one idea would be, to transform into an image and send it as an image

Comment: @ Christian can u please do me a favor although I dont know u, I reached a step where I cant code at all

Comment: @Help19: put it in a zip file and put a password on it.

Comment: @ Christin can u please send me an email, I really need ur contact information

Comment: Why you want my contact info? I updated a working example and can't help you any further.

Comment: well I justed wanted to suggest for u some jobs that u might be interested in thats all ...... thanx again

Comment: Thank you, but at the moment I just don't have the time. Currently working on my master thesis.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the file extension to `.png` or whatever you want.  Operating systems have no notion of what's in a file and what it means; only what program to use when opening it.

If you need security, I recommend reading up a bit on [encryption.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)